# Integration tests when WebConfig is dependency

Tags: .net, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

I've written a good number of unit tests for a new feature I'm implementing and now I'm getting around to writing integration tests, only, I'm now questioning the justification for them in this case.

The feature includes creating an MVC action filter attribute. My unit tests check the paths of logic within the attribute and also check that they're applied to the controller actions we expect.

The feature is driven by the WebConfig, which decides whether an organisation is enabled or not.

I could use the `ConfigurationManager` to set the value before each test is run, but this seems like a test smell to me, or is this common when integration testing when a config file is a dependency?

Comment: what version of asp.net mvc are you using?

Comment: the `app.config` of the test project should be able to hold the necessary settings. Copy the necessary setting over from the `web.config` into the `app.config` of the test project. You should however consider encapsulating the configuration feature behind an abstraction. should allow you to be able to safely mock and set desired values when exercising the tests

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/49449406/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi The project in this particular case is MVC 4. I did abstract out the config so I could mock it for my unit tests. I had to use a wrapper since calls to a static config class were made. The thing is my integration tests aren't merely method calls, they're full system tests in that a Casini server is spun up and HTTP requests made. Also isn't mocking for unit tests?